# Rails 7: <%= %> doesn't show correct values in webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

The error message doesn't show correctly on the webpage, even through `@task.errors.full_messages` is not empty, when I render it in `<%= %>` it doesn't show correctly

here is the file *new.html.erb*:

```
<h1>Tasks#new</h1>

<ul class='error-list'>
    <% p @task.errors.full_messages %>
    <li><em><%= @task.errors.full_messages %></em></li>
    <% p @task.errors.full_messages %>
</ul>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

here is the method:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    if @task.save
      redirect_to tasks_path
    else
      p @task.errors.full_messages
      render 'new'
      p @task.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the output in terminal when I tried to create a task without a title:

> Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-02-13 22:59:16 -0500
>
> Processing by TasksController#create as TURBO_STREAM
>
> Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
> "task"=>{"title"=>"", "details"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
>
> (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
>
> ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:12:in `create'
>
> ["Title can't be blank"]
>
> Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
>
> Rendering tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application
>
> ["Title can't be blank"]
>
> ["Title can't be blank"]
>
> Rendered tasks/_form.html.erb (Duration: 2.3ms | Allocations: 1233)
>
> Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration:
> 3.9ms | Allocations: 2499)
>
> Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 7.5ms |
> Allocations: 4567)
>
> ["Title can't be blank"]
>
> Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms |
> Allocations: 6876)

Here is what the webpage looked like when I tried to create a task without a title::

[image]

Comment: Here is the `Task` model:

`class Task < ApplicationRecord`

`validates :title, presence: true`
`end`

Comment: Because `full_messages` is an array, you'll need to loop through them

Answer (score 0):

`full_messages` returns an array, so you'll need to loop over them if you want to print them

```
<ul class='error-list'>
    <%- @task.errors.full_messages.each do |e| %>
        <li><em><%= e %></em></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@task.errors return array. You use `each` loop this array.

```
  <% if @task.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <ul>
        <% li @task.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def create
      def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    debugger
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: "Task was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```